# Merge some rows into one if a field has same name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem in writing excel macro code. I want to merge some rows if they have the same [name] field there is an [option] field which has *type of key cases, strap types and others* like in the attached picture:

[image]

What I need to do is :

1. delete [no.] columns
2. combine option rows that have same [name] using comma.
3. ascending arrange by option field

For example ->

| [name] | [options] |
| --- | --- |
| james | key case A, strap q, ewr, wer,ewr,wer,gfd,ewr |
| john | strap r,tre,key case B,ert,t34,534,wer,trw |

I have tried my best to accomplish this, but I have got nowhere!

Please, could someone help me with this?  i wanna know macro code to accomplish my objects...

Thanks a lot I really appreciate your help

I tried to merge option fields but failed

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far - see 'Help others reproduce the problem' at this [SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, I recommend posting your data as a table so that other's don't have to manually recreate it from the image you added ... see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using Power Query:

Group by name, with a new column for All Rows

Add a custom column `=[AllRows][options]`

Extract the new column to a list, using a comma for delimiter

Remove other columns

[image]

Here is the M code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"name"}, {"AllRows", each _}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "options", each [AllRows][options]),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"options", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ",")}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"name", "options"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

adapted from the answer here [Pivot and concatenate Power Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66275087/pivot-and-concatenate-power-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
Sub Macro()
Dim lngRow As Long
For lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If StrComp(Range("G" & lngRow), Range("G" & lngRow - 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        If Range("G" & lngRow) <> "" Then
            Range("H" & lngRow - 1) = Range("H" & lngRow - 1) & "," & Range("H" & lngRow)
        End If
    Rows(lngRow).Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]